# SQL query not producing any results

Tags: c#, sql, ms-access

I have a following SQL query that I run inside C# application. I work with local (no servers) database created in access:

```
string query = @"SELECT s.TagID, se.SessionID, '" +
DateTime.Now.ToString("MM/dd/yy HH:mm:ss tt") +
"' AS ScanningTime " +
" FROM (((Student s " +
" LEFT JOIN [CourseID-ModuleID] cm ON s.CourseID = cm.CourseID) " +
" LEFT JOIN [ModuleID-SessionID] ms ON ms.ModuleID = cm.ModuleID) " +
" LEFT JOIN [Session] se ON ms.SessionID = se.SessionID) " +
" WHERE s.TagID = @tagNo " +
" AND se.SessionDate = Date() " +
" AND DateAdd('n', -30, [SessionTimeStart]) < @timeNow   " +
" AND se.SessionTimeEnd > @Plus30Min ";
```

Parameters and variables used in the query:

```
        DateTime TimePlus = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(30);
        DateTime now = DateTime.Now;

        string Plus30Min = TimePlus.ToString("hh:mm tt");
        string timeNow = now.ToString("hh:mm tt");

        command.Parameters.Add("tagNo", OleDbType.Integer).Value = tagNo;
        command.Parameters.Add("Plus30Min", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = Plus30Min;
        command.Parameters.Add("timeNow", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = timeNow;
```

At the moment, this query runs, but does not produce any results. However, if I delete the line:

```
" AND DateAdd('n', -30, [SessionTimeStart]) < @timeNow   " +
```

Then the query runs perfectly. This means that there must be something wrong with this line inside the query. Can you see it somewhere? I looked at multiple websites for examples of date query criteria, but I cannot find the mistake, maybe you will be able to help. Thanks in advance.

The only thing I noticed is the '  sign surrounding n. Should i use quotation mark instead? If so, how can I achieve it inside the quotes?

Comment: What is the type of the `@timeNow` variable?  And why do you implement it so differently from @Plus30Min ?

Comment: To give a plausible answer it is needed to see how do you set the value for the parameter @timenow (and the other parameters as well)

Comment: For starters, you can't quote the `n` like that in `dateadd`. For clarity, write it as `dateadd(minute, -30, SessionStartTime)`. And as others have said, we need to know how you're setting `@timenow`. Aside from the syntax error, my first guess is a time zone issue, like using getutcdate() on the server and DateTime.Now on your system, or vice versa.

Comment: I have updated my code with parameters and variables. The date parameters work in other part of the query, so I dont think that there is something wrong with them

Comment: @mroach This question is tagged [tag:ms-access]. It's about Access SQL, not T-SQL

Comment: Perhaps I am bit lazy, but why don't you do the math in code and pass a @timenow already -30 and remove all the VBA like code in the query (The same you do already with Plus30min)?

Comment: @timeNow must be the current time. I'm trying to substract 30 minutes from the database field.

Comment: mroach - your code: dateadd(minute, -30, SessionStartTime) gives me an error: A first chance exception of type 'System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException' occurred in System.Data.dll
Additional information: No value given for one or more required parameters.

Comment: @GordThompson My bad! It showed up in my SQL Server feed. Hrm...

Comment: @jaspernorth I mistakenly thought you were on SQL Server. Ignore my comment about the parameter usage.

Comment: Switch the query to do the start threshold the same way you do the end threshold. Create a `Minus30Min` variable.  This is not just to eliminate your problem, but because the way you are processing `[SessionTimeStart]` in a DateAdd in your query makes it un-SARGable


  [1]: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sargable.

Comment: OK, if I create a Minus30Min variable, how can I substract it from DB field SessionTimeStart?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your calling code to

```
 DateTime now = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(30);
```

and replace the offending line in query text with

```
" AND SessionTimeStart > @timeNow   "
```

If you need a DateTime.Now somewhere in your code, you could easily obtain again from the same expression. However, I am a bit perplexed by your parameters. They works against Date/Time fields but you pass strings. If the above solution doesn't work try also to change the OleDbType.VarChar to OleDbType.DBTime or DbDate

**EDIT**  Pay attention to the parameter order. You are using OleDB and the name of parameters is meaningless. You should insert the parameters in the parameter collection in the same exact order in which they appears in the query text. The @timenow and Plus30Min should be changed in position.
Your query ends to use the timenow parameter to test the SessioneEndTime and viceversa

```
  command.Parameters.Add("tagNo", OleDbType.Integer).Value = tagNo;
  command.Parameters.Add("timeNow", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = timeNow;
  command.Parameters.Add("Plus30Min", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = Plus30Min;
```

Comment: Thanks Steve, this was my first approach, however, it doest work as it should be. My goal is: SessionTimeStart - 30 minutes > timeNow NOT SessionTimeStart < timeNow-30

Comment: Let me understand, you want to retrieve all the sessions for today and for a particular student where we have still 30 minutes before the starttime of the session and where we have still 30 minutes before the end of the session? Seems incompatible conditions

Comment: Precisely Steve, all sessions on a day for the given tagID, where the session will start in not less then 30 min, and it will last for minimum of 30 min.

Comment: Not quite sure what you want me to do... revert the first condition?

Comment: Probably the error is the parameter order, look at the updated answer.

Comment: I have changed the position of the parameter, but it did not work, still no query results

Comment: Suppose you have a session that starts at 10:00 and now is 09:45. If I add 30min to 9.45 I get 10:15 (@timenow) Checking this value against session start (SessionStartTime > @timenow) should exclude the session while if now is 9:29 the session should be included.

Comment: I need something exactly opposite: If session start at 10:00 and it is now 9:45 it should execute the query, while if id 09:29 it should not, as it is to early (not 30 min.)

Comment: Then still add 30 min in code and check for SessionStartTime < @timenow (9:29 + 30 = 9.59 > 10:00 = false) and please, when testing comment out the line for EndSessionTime because an error there could change the result of the first test

Comment: I have done exactly what you suggested, but still without any luck

Comment: you were right from the very beginning... Thank you so much! Replacing last two lines have solved my problem: 
" AND se.SessionTimeStart <= Plus30Min " +
" AND se.SessionTimeEnd >= Plus30Min ";